# sum(if(...))の数が多いとWebUIからのクエリ実行ができない

Tags: google-bigquery

あるテーブルを縦持ちから横持ちに変換(pivot)しようとしたところ、
カラム数が一定数を超えるとクエリが実行できなくなってしまいました。
構文エラーやエラーチェックなどはでず、単に「クエリが実行できません」というトーストがでます。

具体的には以下のようなクエリになります。

```
with sub as (
 select
   prime
   ,number
   ,sum(prime * number) as multi
 from
   unnest([1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17]) as prime,unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) as number
 group by
   prime, number
)
select
 prime
 , number
 , sum(if(multi= 1, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_1
 , sum(if(multi= 2, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_2
 , sum(if(multi= 3, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_3
 , sum(if(multi= 4, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_4
 // ...
 , sum(if(multi=56, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_56
 , sum(if(multi=57, 1, 0)) as cnt_total_57
from
 sub
group by
 prime, number
order by
 prime, number
```

sum(if(...))のカラムが、50前後になると実行できなくなります。

この問題を回避する方法はあるのでしょうか？